# Is it possible to combine failure stage from groovy with try catch from pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, groovy

I have a pipeline with some stages and logic. The only possible debugger is adding try-catch to each stage:

```
stage ("distribution"){
            steps{
                script{
                    try{
    amd_distribution_distribute_bundle
                    }
                   catch (Exception e) {
                    echo e.toString()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

however, if one stage fails, I need to stop the pipeline:

```
status = sh script: '''
                set +x
                python3.4 main.py --command create_bundle
                ''',  returnStatus:true
             }
        }
     }

    if (status == 1) {
    error("returning 1 from func")
    }
```

but the try-catch from the pipeline actually cancel it (it proceed to other stages. is there a way to combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use and update a flag to `false` in the `catch` and then use that flag in the `when` directive of other stage(s) that you want to skip because of any failure in the given stage. Example:

```
boolean flagStageOneSuccess = false

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('stage-1') {
            steps {
                try {
                    // Do something that might fail

                    flagStageOneSuccess = true

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Handle the exception
                    flagStageOneSuccess = false
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('stage-2') {
            when {
                equals expected: true, actual: flagStageOneSuccess
            }
            steps {
                // Do something in stage-2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would also benefit you in viewing the status of your stage in `Blue Ocean`. If the stage is skipped, it shows as 'Not built'.